# tracking a bone to the average location of 2 bones

Tags: bones

I'm rigging a skeleton and i need the kneecap to be averaged between the rotation of the shin and the femur. I tried making two pull bones for the knee cap to track to hoping it would track to the average of the 2 pull bones but it will only track to the bone on the bottom of the modifier stack. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the influence to .5 on each

[image]

Comment: This must be wrong. The influence on the first modifier (top) should be 1.0.